# JMeter ramp up 1 user every seconds ramp up 1 user every seconds not works properly

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to load test my application using JMeter, the test consists in testing a login that follows the openid flow with a total of 5 rest calls as shown:

[image]

To carry out the test I used the Transaction Controller and the classic rest calls. The problem is that I can't reach my goal, that is to gradually increase the logins starting from 1 up to N at the same time; Let me explain better, I would like a login to take place in the 1st second, 2 simultaneous logins in the 2nd second, etc. up to N simultaneous logins.
I tried to use the Concurrency Thread Group as shown in the figure but the login number is always wrong, in the sense that I expect that for max 5 concurrent users for 5 seconds of testing I should have 1+2+3+4+5 = 15 logins, instead I always have a much higher number. What am I doing wrong? Is it OK to use the Concurrency Thread Group?

**UPDATE**

I followed the advice of @Dmitri T and added the Throughput Shaping Timer with these settings:

[image]

and these:

[image]

The problem is that at the end of each test the response values become very high and I register many socket connection errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login number is not wrong, you don't understand [the relationship between users and hits per second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second)

Let's simplify it a little bit and assume that you have only one Sampler which performs login under the Thread Group.

Your expectation is that:

1. 1st second of the test: 1 user, 1 request, 1 request in total
2. 2nd second of the test: 2 users, 2 requests, 3 requests in total
3. 3rd second of the test: 3 users, 3 requests, 6 requests in total
4. 4th second of the test: 4 users, 4 requests, 10 requests in total
5. 5th second of the test: 5 users, 5 requests, 15 requests in total

It might be true but only if one important condition is met: **the response time of your Login request is 1 second sharp**.

- If you have response time of 500ms - you will get 30 requests.
- If you have response time of 2 seconds - you will get 7 requests.
- etc.

If you want JMeter to perform X requests per second it's OK to use Concurrency Thread Group but I would recommend adding [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) so it would slow down JMeter's throughput to the desired value.